# PHP 7 if...else...elseif Statements

Tags: php

I have function call that have 3 conditions.

Lets call them:

```
condA();
condB();
condC();
```

I want to allow only one condition(A/B/C) at a time. Having a combination of two/three conditions (A&B,A&C,B&C,A&B&C) are not allowed.
If none of them are chosen, it should output a message. 
How could I add restrictions to either allow one condition or none.

Here's my attempt at the code :

```
condA();
condB();
condC();

if(condA() == true)
{ echo '<div>DIV A</div>'; }

if(condB()== true)
{ echo '<div>DIV B</div>'; }

if(condC() == true)
{ echo '<div>DIV C</div>'; }

else
{
    if(condA() == true || condB() == false || condC() == false)
    {  echo '<div>DIV D</div>'; }
    if(condA() == false || condB() == true || condC() == false)
    {  echo '<div>DIV D</div>'; }
    if(condA() == false || condB() == false || condC() == true)
    {  echo '<div>DIV D</div>'; }
    else
    echo '<div>DIV E</div>';
 }

?>
```

Comment: So only one condition can be chosen? Why not just use `if(condA() || condB() || condC())`? Also, `condC` is a function, and requires brackets.

Comment: Your question is clear enough. Kindly modify the question.

Comment: Obsidian Age: There is different div to display for each condition.

Comment: Thank You James Bie, for the question edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using boolean logic will make things unnecessarily complicated, you can use arithmetic instead:

```
if (((bool)condA() + (bool)condB() + (bool)condC()) > 1)
     echo '<div>DIV D</div>';
```

This will ensure the script will proceed only if one condition is met, and no more than one. In case condition is met, you proceed with the individual checks:

```
else
{
    if (condA())
        echo '<div>DIV A</div>';

    else if (condB())
        echo '<div>DIV B</div>';

    else if (condC())
        echo '<div>DIV C</div>';

    else
        echo '<div>DIV E</div>';
}
```

Converting the output of the cond functions to `bool` ensures that the logic works properly. If you guarantee the output of those functions is already of boolean nature (`false`, `0` or `true`, `1`) this conversion is not necessary.

Comment: Havenard: Can you tell me what bool defines here.

Comment: No because the first condition already covers the case when none are chosen. You can change the logic to >1 instead of !=1 if you want it to trigger only if multiple are chosen.